# Generate PDF from html template and send via Email in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, weasyprint, python-pdfkit

I'm trying to generate a pdf file from an HTML template using [Weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org) python package and I need to send it via email using.

Here's what i have tried:

```
def send_pdf(request):
minutes = int(request.user.tagging.count()) * 5
testhours = minutes / 60
hours = str(round(testhours, 3))
user_info = {
    "name": str(request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name),
    "hours": str(hours),
    "taggedArticles": str(request.user.tagging.count())
}
html = render_to_string('users/certificate_template.html',
                        {'user': user_info})
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=certificate_{}'.format(user_info['name'] + '.pdf')
pdf = weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, )
from_email = 'our_business_email_address'
to_emails = ['Reciever1', 'Reciever2']
subject = "Certificate from INC."
message = 'Enjoy your certificate.'
email = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email, to_emails)
email.attach("certificate.pdf", pdf, "application/pdf")
email.send()
return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/pdf')
```

---

> But it returns an error as `TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not HttpResponse`

How can I generate and send a pdf file to an email from HTML template?

> **Update:** With this updated code now it's generating pdf and sending an email but when I open attached pdf file from recieved email it says `unsupported file formate data`.

Here's the updated Code:

```
def send_pdf(request):
minutes = int(request.user.tagging.count()) * 5
testhours = minutes / 60
hours = str(round(testhours, 3))
user_info = {
    "name": str(request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name),
    "hours": str(hours),
    "taggedArticles": str(request.user.tagging.count())
}
html = render_to_string('users/certificate_template.html',
                        {'user': user_info})
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=certificate_{}'.format(user_info['name']) + '.pdf'
pdf = weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf()
from_email = 'arycloud7@icloud.com'
to_emails = ['abdul12391@gmail.com', 'arycloud7@gmail.com']
subject = "Certificate from Nami Montana"
message = 'Enjoy your certificate.'
email = EmailMessage(subject, body=pdf, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=to_emails)
# email.attach("certificate.pdf", pdf, "application/pdf")
email.content_subtype = "pdf"  # Main content is now text/html
email.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
email.send()
return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the complete working version of above code:

```
    user_infor = ast.literal_eval(ipn_obj.custom)
    if int(user_infor['taggedArticles']) > 11:
        # generate and send an email with pdf certificate file to the user's email
        user_info = {
            "name": user_infor['name'],
            "hours": user_infor['hours'],
            "taggedArticles": user_infor['taggedArticles'],
            "email": user_infor['email'],
        }
        html = render_to_string('users/certificate_template.html',
                                {'user': user_info})
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=certificate_{}'.format(user_info['name']) + '.pdf'
        pdf = weasyprint.HTML(string=html, base_url='http://8d8093d5.ngrok.io/users/process/').write_pdf(
            stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(string='body { font-family: serif}')])
        to_emails = [str(user_infor['email'])]
        subject = "Certificate from Nami Montana"
        email = EmailMessage(subject, body=pdf, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=to_emails)
        email.attach("certificate_{}".format(user_infor['name']) + '.pdf', pdf, "application/pdf")
        email.content_subtype = "pdf"  # Main content is now text/html
        email.encoding = 'us-ascii'
        email.send()
```

Comment: following this procedure i was able to generate a pdf but still could't send it as a mail.im having the bellow errorr message:

AssertionError at /forex/1/salary-package/
No exception message supplied
No exception message supplied

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from Weasysprint document, calling method `write_pdf()` will render the document in a single `File`.

http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

> Once you have a HTML object, call its write_pdf() or write_png()
>   method to get the rendered document in a single PDF or PNG file.

Also, they mention that

> Without arguments, these methods return a byte string in memory.

So, you can get its PDF byte string and use it for attachment or pass the filename to write the PDF to.

There is a point that you can also send a writable file-like object to `write_pdf()`.

> If you pass a file name or a writable file-like object, they will
>   write there directly instead.

You can generate and attach the PDF file like this:

```
pdf = weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf()
...
email.attach("certificate.pdf", pdf, "application/pdf")
```

You can also send 200 Response if it was successful or 500 if it failed.

**NOTE About SMTP Server**

Normally you need an SMTP mail server for relaying your message to your destination.

As you can read from Django [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/) `send_mail` need some [configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#email-host):

> Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT settings. The EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD settings, if set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS and EMAIL_USE_SSL settings control whether a secure connection is used.

Then you can use `send_mail()` with following parameters for relaying your message to the local SMTP server.

> send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)

**Attention**: Don't miss authentication parameters.

Comment: Hi @H.Tibat, can you guide me with code example, please?

Comment: Hi @H.Tibat, now it's generating the pdf file but still not sending the email.

Comment: Hi @H.Tibat, I have set up all of the required SMTP settings but `send_mail` method doesn't provide a way to attach a file.To attach a file I think we need to use EmailMessage which is not working anyhow.

Comment: Hi @H.Tibat, take a look at the updated code, please!

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me

```
    template = get_template('admin/invoice.html')
    context = {
        "billno": bill_num,
        "billdate": bill_date,
        "patientname": patient_name,
        "totalbill": total_bill,
        "billprocedure": invoice_cal,

    }

    html  = template.render(context)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)#, link_callback=fetch_resources)
    pdf = result.getvalue()
    filename = 'Invoice.pdf'
    to_emails = ['receiver@gmail.com']
    subject = "From CliMan"
    email = EmailMessage(subject, "helloji", from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=to_emails)
    email.attach(filename, pdf, "application/pdf")
    email.send(fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Rishabh gupta answer:

```
import io

from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from weasyprint import HTML

context = { "name": 'Hello', }
html_string = render_to_string('myapp/report.html', context)
html = HTML(string=html_string)
buffer = io.BytesIO()
html.write_pdf(target=buffer)
pdf = buffer.getvalue()

email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    to=("youremailadress@gmail.com",),
    subject="subject test print",
    body="heres is the body",
)
filename = 'test.pdf'
mimetype_pdf = 'application/pdf'
email_message.attach(filename, pdf, mimetype_pdf)
email_message.send(fail_silently=False)  # TODO zzz mabye change this to True
```